# how to make gsub method only change once

Tags: ruby

I didn't word the title well as i can't rly explain it but if i had lets say i have something like this

```
puts ("red, blue").gsub("red", "blue").gsub("blue", "red")
```

I want to make it so that "red, blue" becomes "blue, red" which are the opposites of one another, but because the "red" becomes a "blue and then the "blue" becomes a "red" right back again, it just dosent work.

I tried this for another method that i wanted to make where for all instance of the word "happy" to be replaced by "sad" and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

You can provide substitutions as a hash. Keys to match the pattern (must be strings), values are replacement:

```rb
>> "red, blue, blue, green".gsub(/red|blue/, {"red" => "blue", "blue" => "red"})
=> "blue, red, red, green"
```

```rb
>> "happy happy sad".gsub(/sad|happy/, {"sad" => "happy", "happy" => "sad"})
=> "sad sad happy"
```

---

For a more complicated operation:

```rb
"happy happy sad red blue".gsub(/\w+/) do |m|
  case m
  when "happy" then "red"
  when "sad"   then "blue"
  when "red"   then "sad"
  when "blue"  then "happy"
  end
end
=> "red red blue sad happy"
```

---

*https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/string#class-String-label-Substitution+Methods*

Comment: You should use word boundaries around the search terms, to avoid unwanted substring matches.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Ruby's `gsub()` function with a block, e.g.

```rb
puts 'red, blue'.gsub(/\b(?:red|blue)\b/) { |word| word == "red" ? "blue" : "red" }
=> "blue, red"
```

The idea here is to a global search for either `red` or `blue`.  The match is then passed to a block (usually called a callback or lambda function in other programming languages), which swaps `red` for `blue` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Use temperary placeholder like this

```
str = "red, blue"
placeholder = "###TEMP_PLACEHOLDER###"

result = str.gsub("red", placeholder).gsub("blue", "red").gsub(placeholder, "blue")

puts result
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the `placeholder` would not already appear anywhere in the input.  If not, then unwanted replacements could occur.

Comment: You can easily handle this by using a very unlikely placeholder, like "###TEMP_PLACEHOLDER###" just as the responder uses.